# convert go-pg query into plain sql

Tags: go, go-pg

Is it possible to convert [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg#look--feel) query

```
err = db.Model(story).
        Relation("Author").
        Where("story.id = ?", story1.Id).
        Select()
```

into plain SQL?

It would be helpful for debugging. So I could copy this plain SQL query and run in psql client as a string.
Probably there is some kind of package for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been upgrading from go-pg v7 to v10 & had a problem where `Query.AppendFormat()` which is what I was using to get the RAW SQL had been removed.

After using the comments in this post for inspiration I managed extract it, using the code below

```golang
import (
    "github.com/go-pg/pg/v10/orm"
)

func QueryToString(q *orm.Query) string {
    value, _ := q.AppendQuery(orm.NewFormatter(), nil)

    return string(value)
}
```

Hope this helps future viewers

Answer (score 2):

This is listed in the project's wiki:

> [How to view queries this library generates?](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-viewlog-queries-this-library-generates)

**How to view queries this library generates?**

You can setup query logger like this:

```
type dbLogger struct { }

func (d dbLogger) BeforeQuery(c context.Context, q *pg.QueryEvent) (context.Context, error) {
    return c, nil
}

func (d dbLogger) AfterQuery(c context.Context, q *pg.QueryEvent) (context.Context, error) {
    fmt.Println(q.FormattedQuery())
    return c, nil
}

db := pg.Connect(&pg.Options{...})
db.AddQueryHook(dbLogger{})
```

Comment: I am getting this issue `db.AddQueryHook undefined (type *pg.DB has no field or method AddQueryHook)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem: There is no default parsing to RAW sql from ORM since v10.

---

Well, that's too late i guess. Maybe someone (like me) will face this problem in 2021. There is some steps how you could solve this:

- [x] Read DOCs.
- [x] Check all structs.
- [x] Implement all methods.

#### Solving the problem

---

This solve is "forked" from this [issue](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/1366) but i'll explain it step by step.
First of all we need to read some [source code](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/v10/hook.go#L46) of go-pg hook.
As I said before: we need to check all structs from this doc. But we're lucky. There is only 1 struct!

```golang
// QueryEvent ...
type QueryEvent struct {
    StartTime  time.Time
    DB         orm.DB
    Model      interface{}
    Query      interface{}
    Params     []interface{}
    fmtedQuery []byte
    Result     Result
    Err        error

    Stash map[interface{}]interface{}
}
```

We don't really need to implement this struct completely.
But when you use db.AddQueryHook() (where db is ref on our DB connection and AddQueryHook() is method) AddQueryHook() wait's from you this **interface**:

```golang
type QueryHook interface {
    BeforeQuery(context.Context, *QueryEvent) (context.Context, error)
    AfterQuery(context.Context, *QueryEvent) error
}
```

So, we already read DOCs, checked structs. And what's next? Answer is pretty easy:

- Implement all methods.

TBH, I thought that this is harder than it is.
To implement it you just need to create 2 methods of current (new empty) structure that implements functionality of methods above, like this:

1. Creating empty structure
   `type dbLogger struct{}`
2. Adding methods from doc:

```golang
func (d dbLogger) BeforeQuery(c context.Context, q *pg.QueryEvent) (context.Context, error) {
    return c, nil
}

func (d dbLogger) AfterQuery(c context.Context, q *pg.QueryEvent) error {
    fq, _ := q.FormattedQuery()
    fmt.Println(string(fq))
    return nil
}
```

---

I hope this helps everyone who ever encounters this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 //db your *pg.DB
// q your  *orm.Query = db.Model(&yourModel).



 qq := pg.QueryEvent{
            DB:        db,
            Model:     q.TableModel(),
            Query:     q,
        }
 fmt.Println(qq.FormattedQuery())
```

So in your case

```
q:= db.Model(story).
        Relation("Author").
        Where("story.id = ?", story1.Id)
fmt.Println("running SQL:")
qq := pg.QueryEvent{
                DB:        db,
                Model:     q.TableModel(),
                Query:     q,
            }
fmt.Println(qq.FormattedQuery()) 
q.Select()
```